# Show the edit reason in the fixed header of the Suggested Edit review page

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

**TLDR**

[image]

---

**Background**: While reviewing suggested edits, I often scroll down to the very bottom to see what all changes were there. Most of the times it's just code formatting (on Stack Overflow) so after having had a look at everything till the bottom, I just click Approve. But sometimes, **the edit reason is not *immediately* obvious.** In this case, I have to scroll all the way to the top to see the edit reason, then go till the bottom to see if the edit tallied with the reason.

Hence, as shown in the above image, I wish the empty space next to the left of the buttons can be used for this work. That way, even if I scroll to the bottom, the edit reason stays there in front of me, like this:

[image]

---

Comment: Please do not "bump" your post by making null edits. It can be seen as abuse. We've considered your request and have agreed with it, hence the upvotes.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Ok, sorry (though this was my last bump attempt). I was just curious that no staff had checked it out till now and was worried that this'd get stuck in the pile of other questions. Anyway, thanks, won't repeat again ^_^

Comment: It was the weekend in the US, and it's Monday morning now. SE staff don't usually check Meta actively on weekends and US public holidays.

Comment: That is a minor request. There are thousands of other requests, with score much higher than this one. There is really no reason why the team will pick this one among all others. Maybe they will pick it up at some point in the future, or not. There's nothing we can, or should, do.

Comment: @Sonic not relevant. They post official reply to very very few requests. Better not build false hopes.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard The team very recently picked up and implemented a +8/-3 feature request to change the search box color to black.

Comment: @Sonic I'm 99% sure this is something the team discussed internally anyway, and would have done with or without that feature request. You can ask Shog about it to be sure. :)